# My quicksort method is not working as intended

Tags: java, vector, quicksort

I trying make a quicksort method whose only parameter is  MyVector` (which is just a normal vector), but the method is not working as intended and I'm not sure why.

The expected output is supposed to be

```
The element at index 0 is: 7
The element at index 0 is: 10
The element at index 0 is: 28
```

But what I got was

```
The element at index 0 is: 41524
The element at index 1 is: 26432
The element at index 2 is: 51244
```

Driver Class (sample)

```
    MySort.QuickSort(testing);
    System.out.println("The element at index 0 is: "+testing.elementAt(0));
    System.out.println("The element at index 1 is: "+testing.elementAt(1));
    System.out.println("The element at index 2 is: "+testing.elementAt(2));
```

MySort class

```
public static void QuickSort(MyVector vec){
    MyVector lo = new MyVector();
    MyVector hi = new MyVector();
    int loSize = lo.size();
    int hiSize = hi.size();
    if (loSize >= hiSize)
        return;
    int p = (int)vec.elementAt((loSize + hiSize) / 2);   // set pivot, could use median of 3 here
    int i = loSize-1;
    int j = hiSize+1;
    while (true){
        while ((int)vec.elementAt(i) < p) {
        ++i;
        }
        while ((int)vec.elementAt(j) > p) { ;    // decrease j until a[j] <= pivot
        --j;
        }
        if (i >= j)             // break if indices meet or cross
            break;
        swap((int)vec.elementAt(i), (int)vec.elementAt(j));
    }
    QuickSort(lo);        
    QuickSort(hi); 
      }
public static void swap(int a, int b) {
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
```

Comment: I don't think your swap is going to work, as you not actually changing the values contained in the `Vector` (and unless you need synchronised access, would be better off using a `List` of some kind).

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sadly I cant just change to a list. This assignment requires the use of the vector as a prerequisite

Comment: Then the issue is still, you need to swap the elements in the list/vector, not the values

Comment: I just changed the lines to swap the elements bt it didnt work

swap((int)vec.elementAt(i), (int)vec.elementAt(j)); 
to  
swap(vec.elementAt(i), vec.elementAt(j));

and the swap method to

public static void swap(Object object, Object object2) {
     Object temp;
     temp = object;
     object=object2;
     object2=temp;
 }

Comment: Another issue is the `hi`/`lo` concept, these should represent the indices range (or the range you want to sort over), and shouldn't be new vectors.  The pivot would then be the middle pint between these two, this then acts as the comparison value for the result of your logic

Comment: Ive made the modifications, but I only recvied an error in return regarding "while ((int)vec.elementAt(i) < p) {". Here is a paste bin link of the updated code, could fit all of it in  my comment.
https://pastebin.com/esg6i3CK

Answer (score 1):

First, this...

```
swap((int)vec.elementAt(i), (int)vec.elementAt(j));
//...
public static void swap(int a, int b) {
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
```

is wrong.  You swap the values, but you never swap the elements in the `Vector` and because of the way Java works, the swap is lost once the method exists

Instead, it should be something more like...

```
protected void swap(MyVector vector, int index1, int index2) {
    Integer value1 = vector.get(index1);
    Integer value2 = vector.get(index2);
    vector.set(index1, value2);
    vector.set(index2, value1);
}
```

Next, this...

```
MyVector lo = new MyVector();
MyVector hi = new MyVector();
int loSize = lo.size();
int hiSize = hi.size();
if (loSize >= hiSize)
    return;
int p = (int)vec.elementAt((loSize + hiSize) / 2);
```

makes no sense what so ever.  Why are you creating two new (I presume) empty vectors?  How are those going to help you??

The `lo(w)` and `hi(gh)` values should bracket the range over the `Vector` you want to search (ie, from index `lo` to index `hi`).

The `p(ivot)` then represents the "base" comparison value you want to use to determine how best to execute the core logic of the sort.

I'd rewrite it, but to be honest, the logic is wrong.  You should start with a `sort` method which accepts just the `Vector`, from this you then call a seperate `sort` method which takes the `Vector` AND the `lo` (defaulted to `0`) and `hi` (default to the `Vector#size - 1`) values - this forms the bases of your recursion.

This means that when you've done a pass, you then determine the next phase of recursion doing something like...

```
if (low < j) {
    sort(vector, low, j);
}
if (i < high) {
    sort(vector, i, high);
}
```

Now, to me, I would start with a simple class which could encapsulate this workflow and "hide" some of the implementation detail.  You don't "have" to, but it will make some of your work easier, as you don't need to continuously pass the `Vector` around.

The following example basically creates a `Vector`, fills it with some integers and randomise it.

It then sorts the values and prints the values.  Something you should note is that this DOES NOT do a "in place" replacement, that is, the sort will make a copy of the `Vector` first and then sort the copy, returning it to the caller.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Vector<Integer> master = new Vector<>(8);
        for (int index = 0; index < 8; index++) {
            master.add(index);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(master);

        Vector<Integer> sorted = QuickSort.sort(master);
        System.out.println("Unsorted = " + master);
        System.out.println("  Sorted = " + sorted);
    }

    public static class QuickSort {
        private Vector<Integer> master;

        private QuickSort(Vector<Integer> master) {
            // Make a shallow copy
            this.master = new Vector<>(master);
        }

        public static Vector<Integer> sort(Vector<Integer> master) {
            QuickSort quickSort = new QuickSort(master);
            return quickSort.sort();
        }

        protected Vector<Integer> sort() {
            sort(0, master.size() - 1);
            return master;
        }

        protected void sort(int low, int high) {
            int i = low, j = high;

            // Get the pivot element
            int pivot = low + (high - low) / 2;
            Integer value = master.get(pivot);

            System.out.println("low = " + low + "; high = " + high);
            // Divide into two lists
            while (i <= j) {

                while (master.get(i) < value) {
                    i++;
                }

                while (master.get(j) > value) {
                    j--;
                }

                if (i <= j) {
                    System.out.println("Swap " + master.get(i) + " <> " + master.get(j));
                    swap(i, j);
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }

            // Recursion
            if (low < j) {
                sort(low, j);
            }
            if (i < high) {
                sort(i, high);
            }
        }

        protected void swap(int index1, int index2) {
            Integer value1 = master.get(index1);
            Integer value2 = master.get(index2);
            master.set(index1, value2);
            master.set(index2, value1);
        }
    }
}
```

I would consider taking a look at:

- [QuickSort – Data Structure and Algorithm Tutorials](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/)
- [Quicksort Algorithm Implementation in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-quicksort)
- [Quick Sort Algorithm](https://www.javatpoint.com/quick-sort)

for some more details about how quick sorts generally work